# How to read uncommited transaction within sqltransaction?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, .net-2.0

i got a problem when using SQLTransaction in my .net framework 2.0 c# code

this is my code:

```
public bool register()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = DB.getInstance().getConnection();
        conn.Open();
        SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Transaction = sqlTransaction;          

        try
        {
            cmd = insertMembers(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader read = null;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='" + username + "'";
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.HasRows)
            {
                id0 = (int)read["id0"];
            }

            cmd = insertMembersBalance(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd = insertMembersEPoint(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd = insertMembersVerify(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            reset();

            sqlTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {                
            sqlTransaction.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I can't get the id from members table to use for insert another records into another table.

is there any other solution?

Comment: "I can't get the id from members table to use for insert another records into another table." - Why can't you?

Comment: i get this error$exception {"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."}

Comment: Remember, you can answer your own question, so post it below and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Please add your answer *as an answer* and then accept that when you're able to.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `dr.Read()` first than  `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.........`

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (read.HasRows)  // needs to be if not while or it will just loop
        {
             read.Read();
             id0 = (int)read["id0"];
        }
        read.Close();      // need to close the reader before you can use the cmd

        if you want to loop through all rows then 

        while (read.Read())
        {
             id0 = (int)read["id0"];
        }
```